# Averaging multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, average

Let's say I have created a dataframe by

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
'A':pd.Series(['aa','aa','bb','bb']),
'B':pd.Series(['xx','yy','zz','zz']), 'C':pd.Series([1,2,3,4]),
'D':pd.Series([11,12,13,14]), 'E':pd.Series([41,42,43,44])
})
```

and the result should be:

```
A   B  C   D   E
0  aa  xx  1  11  41
1  aa  yy  2  12  42
2  bb  zz  3  13  43
3  bb  zz  4  14  44
```

and I would like to average 'C', 'D' and 'E' grouped by 'A' and 'B'. I know that I can use

```
pd.DataFrame({'C_avg' : df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].mean()}).reset_index()

pd.DataFrame({'D_avg' : df.groupby(['A','B'])['D'].mean()}).reset_index()

pd.DataFrame({'E_avg' : df.groupby(['A','B'])['E'].mean()}).reset_index()
```

to get seperate average values. However I would like my end product to be a dataframe like

```
A   B  C_avg  D_avg  E_avg
0  aa  xx    1.0    11.0    41.0
1  aa  yy    2.0    12.0    42.0
2  bb  zz    3.5    13.5    43.5
```

i.e. like this dataframe:

```
df_avg=pd.DataFrame({
'A':pd.Series(['aa','aa','bb']),
'B':pd.Series(['xx','yy','zz']),
'C_avg':pd.Series([1.0,2.0,3.5]),
'D_avg':pd.Series([11.0,12.0,13.5]),
'E':pd.Series([41.0,42.0,43.5])
})
```

is there any quick or cleaner way? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
In [237]: df.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean().add_suffix('_avg').reset_index()
Out[237]:
    A   B  C_avg  D_avg  E_avg
0  aa  xx    1.0   11.0   41.0
1  aa  yy    2.0   12.0   42.0
2  bb  zz    3.5   13.5   43.5
```

---

Details

```
In [238]: df
Out[238]:
    A   B  C   D   E
0  aa  xx  1  11  41
1  aa  yy  2  12  42
2  bb  zz  3  13  43
3  bb  zz  4  14  44
```